# Cloudflare scrubbing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when in Under Attack Mode

Tags: cloudflare, cors

I need to be able to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header with my server, however when I switch to Under Attack Mode (which I need right now because I'm being DDOSed), Cloudflare scrubs this and a bunch of other headers which is breaking some site functionality I need.

I sent a message to Cloudflare and am waiting to hear back, any ideas in the meantime?

Comment: In the meantime you could try a different CDN, but DNS caching means that might not be very effective.

Comment: I switched to a different DDOS mitigation service and the CORS is even more messed up because they scrub even more headers.

Comment: There's probably a reason they do that then.

Comment: @Tim, well it's just CORS, it can be spoofed client side anyways if someone is really eager enough, I think my best bet is to exclude that route from the firewall, I'll talk with Cloudflare and see if that's possible